# Does DevonThink Pro Office support the Macbook Pro Retina display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I'm considering getting a Macbook Pro with retina display, but I can't seem to figure out if DevonThink Pro Office, which I use for my research, will support the retina display. Since it is a program which primarily processes text I will be very disappointed if it doesn't display properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual](https://s3.amazonaws.com/DTWebsiteSupport/download/devonthink/2.5.2/DEVONthink%20Pro%20Office%20Manual.pdf), on page 9, states that retina graphics were added in version 2.5 (the current version is 2.5.2). So you should be ok.